# Optimizing VBA including AND statement within IF

Tags: vba, ms-word

I was wondering if there was a way to optimize this set of code

```
 Sub BBG_Transmital()
 'Hides Sections Not Used in Expanded Form
     Dim CollapseRange1 As Range
     Dim CollapseRange2 As Range
     'Set Which Range/Cell to Associate with Marked CheckBox
     With ActiveDocument.Tables(3)
    Set CollapseRange1 = .Rows(10).Range
         CollapseRange1.End = .Rows(13).Range.End
     End With
     With ActiveDocument.Tables(3)
     Set CollapseRange2 = .Rows(16).Range
         CollapseRange2.End = .Rows(21).Range.End
     End With

    'If Box is Checked then CollapseRanges
     If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
        CollapseRange1.Font.Hidden = True
    'If Box is Not Checked then UncollapseRange
    Else
        CollapseRange1.Font.Hidden = False
    End If
    'If Box is Checked then CollapseRanges
    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
        CollapseRange2.Font.Hidden = True
    'If Box is Not Checked then UncollapseRange
   Else
        CollapseRange2.Font.Hidden = False
    End If

End Sub
```

I tried using

```
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    CollapseRange1.Font.Hidden = True AND CollapseRange2.Font.Hidden = True
Else 
    CollapseRange1.Font.Hidden = False And CollapseRange2.Font.Hidden = False
```

But it didn't work.  I was just wondering if I can shorten my IF statement into one rather then two.

Thanks!

Comment: You have two "If CheckBox1.Value = True Then"... why not have just one?  Plus combine the "With Active..."

Comment: I want to have one.  I just don't know how to write it as one, so I was wondering if you can help me with that. @WayneG.Dunn

Answer (score 3):

Here is your same code... just condensed to remove unnecessary checks

```
 Sub BBG_Transmital()
    'Hides Sections Not Used in Expanded Form
     Dim CollapseRange1 As Range
     Dim CollapseRange2 As Range

     'Set Which Range/Cell to Associate with Marked CheckBox
    With ActiveDocument.Tables(3)
        Set CollapseRange1 = .rows(10).Range
        CollapseRange1.End = .rows(13).Range.End
        Set CollapseRange2 = .rows(16).Range
        CollapseRange2.End = .rows(21).Range.End
    End With

    'If Box is Checked then CollapseRanges
    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
        CollapseRange1.Font.Hidden = True
        CollapseRange2.Font.Hidden = True

    Else    'If Box is Not Checked then UncollapseRange
        CollapseRange1.Font.Hidden = False
        CollapseRange2.Font.Hidden = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `If {boolean-expression} = True Then` is redundant, too

Comment: Thanks! I thought I had to use AND within the statement. Guess I didn't need to!

Comment: Yes, @Mat'sMug  it can be "If CheckBox1.Value Then", but I'm gonna play my senior citizen card that allows me to.... hmmm, what were we talking about?

Answer (score 2):

Further condensing [Wayne's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44186400/1188513):

This part:

```
'If Box is Checked then CollapseRanges
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    CollapseRange1.Font.Hidden = True
    CollapseRange2.Font.Hidden = True

Else    'If Box is Not Checked then UncollapseRange
    CollapseRange1.Font.Hidden = False
    CollapseRange2.Font.Hidden = False
End If
```

Can be written as:

```
CollapseRange1.Font.Hidden = CheckBox1.Value
CollapseRange2.Font.Hidden = CheckBox1.Value
```

Also note, `If {boolean-expression} = True` can always be rewritten as `If {boolean-expression}`, and `If {boolean-expression} = False` can always be rewritten as `If Not {boolean-expression}`.

Comment: OHH! That's good to know.  I did not not it can be written that way!